# how to test Telegram bot built with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I made a Telegram bot with NodeJS (node-telegram-bot-api) but right now I am facing an issue is to how to test the bot. I want to test how the bot responds when a message is given to it, how can I simulate that using Node itself and write automated tests based on that. I feel this is not possible but is here anybody which achieved it?
I have already tried researching the internet, didn't find anything satisfactory.

Comment: A bot is a simple web-service that gets HTTP requests and sends HTTP requests, so usual methods for testing such things should work.

Comment: May [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42489240/11147608) be useful for you?

Comment: I saw that post earlier but didn't found it easy to use the suggestions given there. They have just listed the libraries (and the documentation didn't help me either). If someone can write a simple hello world test for a bot, that will be helpful.

Answer (score -2):

Its very simple if you use telegraf library. You will have all built in telegram api capability and its simple to code.

For example : this bot will respond "Hello There" to every text messages sent to the bot.

```
const { Telegraf } = require("telegraf");

const bot = new Telegraf("YOUR_BOT_TOKEN_HERE");

bot.on("text", async (ctx) => {
  ctx.reply("Hello There");
});

bot.launch();
process.once("SIGINT", () => bot.stop("SIGINT"));
process.once("SIGTERM", () => bot.stop("SIGTERM"));
```

You can make it smart and intelligent with hooking it up with NLP library.

I  created a tutorial on how to create build a smart telegram chatbot with AI/ML capability that using WIT.AI as the NLP engine to help to inteprete message

https://youtu.be/YIeEermeXEU

You can download the source code as well.